# count number of entries in a csv file with mysql to determine further handling

Tags: php, mysql, performance, csv

I'm receiving different csv files for different customers. The number of entries in this files differ from 1 to more than 100,000 rows. (And for different operations from 3 to 40 columns)

Right now, I do a checkup like this

```
private function determineFurtherHandling($file)
{
    if (count($file) > 10000)
    {
        return $uploadMethod = 'LOAD_DATA_LOCAL_INFILE';
    }

    return $uploadMethod = 'STANDARD';
}
```

To determine if my program should use load data local infile or a standard insert query to upload the data to my DB. I would like to avoid loading the file with php with

```
$file = file('response.csv');
```

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to do this checkup directly in a mysql query, but can't seem to find a reliable answer to this. So my question, is there a way to get rid of the checkup and let mysql determine this with a CASE WHEN statement or anything else?

Comment: If you want to use a CASE that the data has to be already in mysql...

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, too. @Mihai. But is there any way to don't load the file with php for the check? I don't think there is, but who knows..

Comment: _“To determine if my program should use load data local infile or a standard insert query to upload the data to my DB”_ – and why not simply use the first method for any file, regardless of its size …?

Comment: Because it takes longer to load data local infile if there is only one or a few lines to use load data local infile compared with insert into/update. I receive loads of those files (a few every second), so I'm in need of a performance optimized solution. @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check the number of lines but check file size. `100000` doesn't need to be a hard limit...

Comment: I had this in mind and think it's a good solution, though it will be hard to determine as the number of columns can differ, too.

Comment: In this case you can read first line of csv to take number of columns into account.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid loading the entire file, you can user this function

```
/**
  * @param $file string : the realtive/absolute path to file + the filename
  * @return integer : the number of lines in the file. NULL if error when opening the file
  *
  */
function numberOfLines ($file) {
    $line = 0;

    $handler = fopen ($file, 'r');
    if (!handler) return NULL;
    while (!feof ($handler)) $line++;
    fclose ($handler);
    return $line;
}
```